# Overwriting a style with sm:

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want my borders to be on top for mobile like devices and on the left for others.
It's working on mobile but for others it's adding the properties.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" alt="login image" class="rounded-t-lg sm:rounded-l-lg">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are adding `rounded-t-lg` without a prefix, it takes effect on all screen sizes.

To hide the top border on screens at the sm breakpoint you will have to add `sm:rounded-t-none`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" alt="login image" class="rounded-t-lg sm:rounded-t-none sm:rounded-l-lg">
</body>

</html>
```